# Most appropriate way to get this: $($(".answer")[0])

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Suppose I want to get the first element amongst all the elements of the class ".answer"

```
$($(".answer")[0])
```

I can do the above, but what is the best balance between elegance and speed?

*changed the question to reflect the current discussion

Comment: From my own experience I have found that `.first` can be really inefficient in IE and that `$($(foo)[0])` was significantly faster. This only matters in critical code (think `.each` on large sets)

Comment: Your version, while inelegant, seems to be by far the most efficient.

Comment: Funny how a question about elegance turned into performance benchmarking.

Comment: @box9 this is an amazing illustration of the power of SO

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The following are all equivalent in functionality (though not speed):

- `var a0 = $($('.answer')[0]);`
- `var a0 = $('.answer').first();` - see http://api.jquery.com/first/
- `var a0 = $('.answer:first');` - see http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
- `var a0 = $('.answer').eq(0);` - see http://api.jquery.com/eq/
- `var a0 = $('.answer:eq(0)');` - see http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

**Which is the best?**
It [has been hypothesized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262928/jquery-what-is-faster-selectors-or-methods/4262951#4262951) that the selector versions *should* be faster than the method versions (and the logic makes some sense) but I have not yet found a reliable cross-browser, multi-document benchmark that proves this to be true.

*And in some cases you cannot use the selector, as you have a jQuery object resulting from chained results and must later pare it down.*

**Edit**: Based on the excellent information from @yc's tests below, following are the current (2011-Feb-4) test results summarized and compared against a baseline of `.answer:first`:

```
          :first  :eq(0)  .first()  .eq(0)  $($('...')[0])
Chrome 8+   100%     92%      224%    266%       367%
   FF 3.6   100%    100%      277%    270%       309%
  FF 4.0b   100%    103%      537%    521%       643%
 Safari 5   100%     93%      349%    352%       467%
 Opera 11   100%    103%      373%    374%       465%
     IE 8   100%    101%     1130%   1246%      1767%
 iPhone 4   100%     95%      269%    316%       403%
=====================================================
 Weighted   100%     92%      286%    295%       405%
    Major   100%     95%      258%    280%       366%
```

- The **Weighted** line shows the performance weighted by the number of tests per browser; popular browsers (among those testing) are counted more strongly.
- The **Major** line shows the same, only including non-beta releases of the major desktop browsers.

In summary: the hypothesis is (currently) wrong. The methods are significantly faster than the Sizzle selectors, and with almost no exception the OP's code `$($('.answer')[0])` is the fastest of them all!

Comment: `:eq()` is zero-based. Maybe you were thinking of [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), which is one-based?

Comment: Just setup a JSPerf for these http://jsperf.com/selecting-the-first . Please run it on your various browsers :) My first tests seem to indicate that the, contrary to the hypothesis, that the methods are faster than the sizzle selectors. This isn't surprising, since the non-CSS Sizzle selectors are known to be quite slow.

Comment: NB the percentages in the table appear to be speed, not duration.

Answer (score 73):

I can't speak to the elegance aspect, but the performance aspect here actually can make a huge difference.

It looks like, [from a set of JavaScript testing](http://jsperf.com/selecting-the-first/#run), that your original method is actually the *most* efficient one, and contrary to the hypothesizing that the accepted answer linked to, non-CSS Sizzle selectors tend to be *much* less efficient than method selectors. There's a reason for that. The `$('.answer')` can use the browser native `getElementsByClass()` without having to manually traverse the results. The `:first` selector complicates that. In this instance, using the sizzle selectors seems to slow the selection by a factor of between 4-5.

I'd argue that, with jQuery, performance should trump elegance, and all evidence (every single browser I've tested so far!) seems to indicate that OP's inelegant solution is the fastest by a fair amount.

Here are the results of the browsers with the most test runs:

[image]

(The numbers are 'operations per second', so higher numbers are faster, lower numbers are slower.)

Comment: Another test suite is showing similar results: http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-first

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to also run tests on more complex document trees.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you argue that with jQuery, performance trumps elegance?  I'd actually argue the opposite, especially if the user can't tell the difference.

Comment: @Xavi For one selection, the user can't tell the difference, but if you're building a jQuery-heavy application, these differences can add up, particularly in lower end browsers. If one method is literally 5 times faster than another method, that difference makes an impact.

Comment: Fundamentally, I did this to rebut a growing conventional wisdom that the Sizzle selectors are more effective. I was surprised, actually, that OP's version was fastest; I was expecting `.eq(0)` or `.first()` to be faster.

Comment: @çağdaş Feel free to setup a test suite :) The more data, the better. My hypothesis would be that this effect would actually be strengthened for more complex document trees, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Just a quick point to yahelc 's note about performance being important. In mobile browsers, how efficient your js is makes a HUGE, extremely noticeable difference to the UX

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector or the [`.first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) filter method:

```
$(".answer:first");
```

or:

```
$(".answer").first();
```