# How to target only first children with find?

Tags: jquery

How do I select only the first children like:

```
$('ul.menu > li').addClass('first_li');
```

But with find() method ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `children()` which is equivalent to your selector `$('ul.menu > li')`:

```
$('ul.menu').children('li').addClass('first_li');
```

Comment: actually just $('ul.menu').children('li').addClass('first_li'); works! first-child only selects one li tag. +1

Comment: I meant first children as I said in the question, not just first child. So if there are more descendants I didnt want to target them. What I wanted is accomplished with the code from my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, i re-read your question and realize i absolutely misunderstand it, sorry, my bad! But, you shouldn't use .find() but children() which will be more accurate here and by the way faster

Answer (score 2):

> I meant first children as I said in the question, not just first child. So if there are more descendants I didnt want to target them.

A simple way coming from your original selector, would be to just:

```
$('ul.menu').find('> li').addClass('first_li');
```

[See demo targeting direct children here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/YjTrh/3/).

Or `.children('li')` as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're only doing this for style reasons, consider using CSS selectors:

```
ul.menu li { border-top: 1px solid black; }
ul.menu li:first-child { border-top: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right on with `:first`, but you also need to know that a different method is almost 4 times faster than the `:first` selector (mostly because you're avoiding another selector query).

```
$($('ul.menu').find('li')[0]).addClass('first_li');
```

See this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837885/1253312

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
$('ul.menu').find('li').eq(0).addClass('first_li');
```