# Which is more efficient - $('selector').last() or $('selector:last')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent element with a real lot of child elements (1000s). I am looking for the fastest possible way to get a handle to the last child element. The options I've found are:

```
$('.parent .child').last()
```

and

```
$('.parent .child:last')
```

Any opinions on which one is reliably faster across browsers?

**EDIT**

I wrote a test in jsfiddle to measure this out and it turns out the difference is pretty much negligible. Though .last() was performing better, the difference is negligible. So i think even with the :last selector, it is actually getting the whole list of elements and then returning the last element? Unbelievable.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/GFb9f/8/

Comment: Consider a jsperf test case for such questions ..

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262928/jquery-what-is-faster-selectors-or-methods

Comment: @pst - Have never used jsperf. Thank for pointing out. I've created a fiddle to measure it though. Link in updated question.

Comment: Surely **the** fastest method is to use `element.lastChild`. Unless you are searching for descendents as opposed to children. Also consider `var els = document.querySelectorAll('.parent .child'); $(els[els.length - 1])`.

Comment: Note that the [`:last` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) says "To achieve the best performance when using `:last` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":last")`."

Comment: @nnnnnn - Yes, that's what i thought of resorting to. But for 20K child item entries, they all performed pretty much without difference, so went with .last() as it is the most readable (imho).

Comment: Yeah, I think `.last()` is _way_ better than `.filter(":last")`. Just guessing here, but I think perhaps the reason the `:last` doco doesn't mention `.last()` is that `:last` is from version 1.0 and `.last()` is from 1.4...

Comment: With reference to RobG's comment above, `$(els).get(-1);` is more concise than `$(els[els.length - 1])`, though I can't comment on the relative efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many modern browsers support `document.querySelectorAll()`, so `$('.parent .child').last()` should be faster, as the selector string can be passed *as is*, and then the last matched item popped off.

In the latter, the `:last` is not a standard pseudo selector, and Sizzle has to start chunking the selector string to start matching.

Overall though, I would use what you believe is the most readable. To begin optimising this, first ensure that your application has performance issues and you have identified this selector as the bottleneck.

Comment: How does sizzle decide whether it's possible to pass a selector as-is or not?

Comment: @zerkms From memory, wraps a call in try/catch, and does its string parsing in the catch block. I haven't checked the source recently though.

Comment: @RobG: so you propose to answer RTFS to any comment?

Comment: I did a fiddle to test this out (haven't used jsperf till now) - and it seems .last() turns out to be the winner even if marginally.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I guess i 'll go with .last() as it suits my taste of readability as well as performance..

Comment: @zerkms—you need to turn up the gain on your sarcasm-o-meter. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to see this [performance test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-last-selector-vs-last-method)!

**UPDATE**: There are already good answers on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262928/jquery-what-is-faster-selectors-or-methods).

Comment: Thanks @RobinMaben - for the links. Very informative. I guess i 'll be going with .last() as it suits my taste of readability as well as performance..

Comment: @techfoobar: I just scanned through your blog. Neat stuff. Totally agree with *`code that can’t be read shouldn’t have been written`*. :)

Comment: @RobinMaben - Thank you. :) The blog's been sleeping for a while now! Need to put up some stuff there..