# What selector is more efficient

Tags: jquery, selector

I am using jQuery and I want to know which selector is faster but I have no idea where to start testing it. I understand that the most efficient selector (fastest) is using id like `$("#xxx")`.

But what about `$("img[data-src]")` or `$("[data-src]")`? What is the most efficient? I know selectors are read from right to left, so I should assume that removing "img" from the selector makes it faster? If so, do you have any idea of a code I can run on my page to check 1000 times which selector is the fastest?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. It's a simple question of what selector is faster not what is faster, selectors or methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, selectors go in this order of efficiency (from most to least efficient):

- ID
- Class
- Tag name
- Child relationship  (`foo > bar`)
- Descendant relationship (`foo bar`)
- Attribute (`foo[bar="baz"]`)
- Pseudo-classes (`foo:hover`, `foo:nth-child()`)

Another consideration is that CSS selectors are basically a tree search, so the more you can trim out of the tree, the better.  `#foo .bar` is a descendant relationship, but if including `#foo` is going to exclude a lot of your HTML from the search, that'll make that selector more efficient.  Similarly `img[data-src]` would theoretically be faster than `[data-src]` because there's a more limited set of elements whose attribute needs to be checked.

(I don't know this for certain but would expect that the CSS rules are *not* always interpreted in strict right-to-left order.  `#foo .bar` for example would be more efficient if interpreted left to right: look for the ID element first, then you only have to test its children for `.bar` instead of searching the whole document.  I would assume that obvious performance optimizations like that are already built in to most or all browser engines.)

There are also some cases where you can substitute javascript methods for css rules, such as `$('foo:nth-child(1)')` vs `$('foo').first()` -- in that specific case [jQuery is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262928/jquery-what-is-faster-selectors-or-methods) though this isn't generalizable to all selectors of course (as there aren't corresponding methods for all of them).

When in doubt you can benchmark this kind of stuff by just re-running the selection (against your real HTML) in a loop:

```js
benchmark = function(selector) {
  var t1 = new Date();
  for (var i=0; i<100000; i++) {
      var x = $(selector);
  }
  var t2 = new Date();

  console.log(selector, t2-t1, "ms")
}

benchmark('[data-src="bar"]')
benchmark('img[data-src="bar"]')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div data-src="bar"></div>
  <img data-src="bar">
</div>
```

...the results of which brings me to my main point:  premature optimization.

In most cases, with most web pages, this makes very little real-world difference. With the very simple HTML above, the selector makes almost no difference at all even at 100,000 iterations. At 10,000 iterations I don't even get consistent results on which one is faster.

If you're working with relatively large HTML trees and complicated selectors, and start to see actual performance problems that you suspect are related to these DOM searches, *then* it's a good idea to start testing this sort of thing.  (Though even then, much of the time you'll see more improvement from cacheing and reusing previous selections than from fine-tuning the selections themselves.)

Use common sense, try to keep your selectors simple and to the point, and reuse them when possible --  but it's probably not worth sweating over every millisecond unless you're seeing real performance issues.

Comment: Wow very clear and, despite some of your opinions not having a proof, they are very logic and with the code you provided anything can be tested! For some reason I used your code on my website and `[data-src]` was 8% faster than `img[data-src]` (8% is not high enought to tell me with certain which case is better but in doubt I will use `[data-src]`.

Comment: I'm sure there's a ton of variation depending on the particular html being searched (and the particular engine doing the search), yeah. The whole answer probably could be boiled down to "when in doubt, run a test" :)

Answer (score 2):

`$("img[data-src]")` is a faster selector as it will only need to look at `img` tags where as `$("[data-src]")` will look at every element in the DOM with that attribute.

Comment: I thought the selector would first check the attr and then the type. I thought it would read from "right to left". Anyway, if you are sure about that I thank you so much!

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262928/jquery-what-is-faster-selectors-or-methods method is faster than selector.

Comment: If it was `$("img .class[data-src]")` then it would be reading right to left with the class selector and then the tag. But in this case, we are only looking at a single selector.